# Can the Swamp Rat's special ability be used to end combat?

Tags: xia

In Xia: Legends of a Drift System, one of the ships, named "Swamp Rat", has a special ability that allows it to trigger one of it's own outfits as a defense to an incoming attack.  If the outfit triggered is an Engine, and the resulting movement breaks the line-of-sight of the incoming attack, does the attack resolve normally, or has the movement prevented it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swamp rat's ability allows it to place a damage marker on an outfit instead of an armed marker to perform an action but only when that action is valid. The engine cannot be used to make a move action when defending against an attack. Therefore you cannot use the swamp rat's ability to move to escape combat. You could, however, use it to power the shields one more time.